# Number of revolutions of a rolling coin

Tags: homework-and-exercises, geometry

Take two quarters and lay them on a table. Press down on one quarter so it cannot move. Then, starting at the 12:00 position, roll the other quarter
along the edge of the stationary quarter.
How many revolutions does the rolling quarter make when it travels once around the circumference of the stationary quarter?

[image]

** Taken from Cutnell & Johnson book Pyhsics 9th Edition.

I need a hint for this one. Could anybody help me?

When thinking of a solution I keep coming up with answer of 1 complete revolution. But that's a wring one.

Comment: This is a fun problem. Unfortunately it's off topic for Physics.SE since it's basically a *Can you help me solve this problem* question.

Comment: Are you asking about rotations or revolutions? The number of revolutions will always be 1 which is defined by the question "travels once around the circumference"

Answer (score 0):

At the 3:00 position, it would have moved half a circumference.

At the 6:00 position, it would have moved 1 complete revolutions, since the top of the moving coin would touch the bottom of the stationary coin. In other words, the top of the moving coin still remains at the top.

Therefore, the answer is 2 complete rotations.

Answer (score 0):

Start by looking at the coin in a frame of reference that is centered on the stationary coin and that is always "looking" at the rotating coin. You will see the coin make one complete revolution. The easiest way to convince yourself of this it to imagine that you have a "mirror image" coin - both of them with the numbers 1-12 (like a clock), but one the mirror image of the other. You see 1 touching 1, 2 touching 2, etc. At the end you have seen the coin make a complete revolution - *in the rotating frame*

Now go back to the lab frame. You see the coin make a second revolution.

Illustration:

[image]